# How to prove that a in-circle of a triangle covers the maximum area among all the circles which are contained in that triangle?

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, area, maxima-minima

How to prove that a in-circle of a triangle covers the maximum area among all the circles which are contained in that triangle?

Can anyone please tell me how to proceed to prove that?

Comment: If a circle is inside a triangle and doesn't touch any side, then you can increase the radius to touch at least one side, thus increasing the are. If once it touches one side it doesn't touch any other side, then you can move the center away from that side, along the perpendicular to that side until it separates from the side. This doesn't change the area, but it makes it not touch any side again. Then you can repeat the first procedure to increase the area once again. Assume now that it is touching two sides but not three. Then it is on the bisector of the angle. Move the center ...

Comment: along the bisector of the angle, away from the vertex. This makes the circle not touch the sides again. Repeat the first step again, but note that because the center is still in the bisector, once it touch one o those sides again, it will touch the other. This loop of third and first steps can be done until the circle touches all three sides. Since the circle was always increasing area throughout the process, and we started with any circle inside the triangle, then the incircle has area greater than or equal to any circle inside the triangle.